# How can I debug runtime library interpositioned process?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, library-interposition

I'm now studying library interpositioning with C in Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm testing two simple codes to wrap `strlen`: "mystrlen.c", "mystrlenTest.c".

Here is the code I wrote: mystrlen.c

```
#ifdef RUNTIME
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

/* strlen wrapper function */
size_t strlen(const char *str) {
    size_t (*strlenp)(const char *) = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", *str);

    strlenp = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "strlen");   // Get address of libc strlen
    printf("length: %ld\n", strlenp(str));

    return strlenp(str);
}
#endif
```

And mystrlenTest.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char testString[] = "Hello World!";
    printf("length of the testString: %ld\n", strlen(testString));

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to inject during runtime with the command below:

```
$ gcc -DRUNTIME -shared -fpic -g -o mystrlen.so mystrlen.c -ldl
$ gcc -g -o mystrlenTest mystrlenTest.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=./mystrlen.so ./mystrlenTest
```

And this is all I get: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
So I tried `dmesg` command to find out what happened, and the result was like below:

```
[842291.658267] mystrlenTest[51446]: segfault at 48 ip 00007f7b918e35a1 sp 00007ffdd7158c88 error 4 in libc-2.27.so[7f7b91755000+1e7000]
[842291.658272] Code: 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 31 c0 c5 f8 77 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 89 f9 48 89 fa c5 f9 ef c0 83 e1 3f 83 f9 20 77 1f <c5> fd 74 0f c5 fd d7 c1 85 c0 0f 85 df 00 00 00 48 83 c7 20 83 e1
```

What I wanted to ask was, how can I debug this with **gdb**?
Or is there any other way to debug it?
I know how to debug a single program with gdb, but I'm having difficulty with *debuging the runtime library interpositioned process*. If I can find out what is in `00007f7b918e35a1`, it would be a great help.

Comment: Well, if `dlsym` calls `strlen` then it will never work. Otherwise you should use `pthread_once` for the initialization. Also you shoul have a thread-level static `call-depth` variable: increment on function-entry, decrement on exit; if it is greater than 1, don't call `printf`.

Comment: Also when you're called from a signal-handler, you shouldn't call `printf`. (Though I cannot tell you how would you know that you're called from a signal-handler.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking gdb, you can pass the environment variables you want to set, like:

```
gdb --args env LD_PRELOAD=./mystrlen.so ./mystrlenTest
```

Now you can use get the backtrace as usual in gdb.

You can also use system calls to print debug messages, such as:

```
write(2, "message", sizeof "message" - 1);
```

Which doesn't call any of the library functions at all. (Although, most system calls have thin wrappers in glibc,this is largely irrelevant for its users).
In your specific case, the likely issue is that `printf` itself calls `strlen` as noted by Andrew Henle, thus resulting in infinite recursion.

When interposing, you need to careful about what you call from the interposed functions and always ask yourself whether any calls from inside the interposed function might result in call back to the same interposed function or any other interposed function(s) and take necessary steps to handle such cases. For example, a lot of standard functions might internally allocate memory via `malloc` family functions and if you're interposing `malloc` and friends, this could cause unexpected problems.

Answer (score 1):

Given this code:

```
size_t strlen(const char *str) {
    size_t (*strlenp)(const char *) = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", *str);

    strlenp = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "strlen");   // Get address of libc strlen
    printf("length: %ld\n", strlenp(str));

    return strlenp(str);
}
```

If `printf()` uses `strlen()` internally, you will get infinite recursion and almost certainly a segmentation violation.

Note that in GLIBC, the `libc.so` used on Linux, [`printf()` is implemented](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/printf.c) via [`vfprintf()`, which does indeed make use of `strlen()`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c).